# Reusing the same buttons for a different scene in JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx, scene

I am trying to reuse my buttons after changing scene.

```
    HBox area = new HBox();
    area.getChildren().addAll(homeButton, loadAPubButton);
    area.setSpacing(20);
    area.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    // Home Scene
    BorderPane homePane = new BorderPane();
    homePane = setupHomeScene(homePane);
    homePane.setTop(area);
    home = new Scene(homePane,1280,960);

    // Load a Pub Crawl Scene
    BorderPane loadPane = new BorderPane();
    loadPane = loadPubCrawl(loadPane);
    loadPane.setTop(area);
    loadPub = new Scene(loadPane,1280,960);
```

This code will use the same HBox on two different scenes however it doesn't seem to work. I am really stuck and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please provide more information how are you affecting scene to stage , ?

Comment: I have a primary stage where the root scene is home. I am not sure what you mean by your question.

Comment: Reusing the same `Node` instance in more than one place is not possible. From the documentation of `Node`: "_A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph. Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the following: as the root node of a Scene, the children ObservableList of a Parent, or as the clip of a Node . . . If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent._"

Comment: Thanks Slaw that explains a lot.